# LWUIT 1.5 VKB issue

Tags: lwuit, codenameone, lwuit-textarea, lwuit-textfield

The native keyboard for BB, opened via LWUIT 1.5 has the following issues,

- The EditField of BB, if it is added to the bottom of the form, doesn't scroll up.
- I am getting a rectangular box (like a selector or a magnifier) when I type something, then again click on the text area
- When I have 2 Textfields, When I click on the first, edit it. touck the same text area (The magnifier pops up) and then click on the 2nd text area, the VKB of the previous is retained. It isn't closed.

If the scrolling up of components is resolved in Codenameone, pls help me to resolve the same in LWUIT 1.5 too .

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear about the problem. We have a few patches for text editing on Blackberry in Codename One such as special TextField properties e.g.

```
ta1.putClientProperty("RIM.nativePopup", "true");
```